# Adding a notification flag on wordpress homepage to indicate an updated custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

I'm creating a wordpress site which needs to notify subscribers that a Custom Post has been updated recently.

I've seen a lot of plugins that send email notifications - I however simply want to create a flag next to the post listed on the front end homepage to indicate that particular post (Or even one of its child posts) has been updated.

Has anyone come across a plugin like this? Or how you'd go about creating this functionality?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ian Dunn's answer on [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60378/notify-admin-when-page-is-edited)

I believe this is exactly what you need.

Comment: No unfortunately this is not what I'm after.
I needed a function that would create a visual display on the front-end of the website for a registered user - Not send them an email.